# Windows Dism.exe /RestoreHealth /LimitAccess, no /Source, Where is the Features on Demand location and should I use it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, dism, sfc

Regarding the command `Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /LimitAccess`

Normally `/RestoreHealth` is used without `/LimitAccess`, which makes Dism use Windows Update to compare against the machine's Component Store.

You can also specify a source to compare against, for example `/Source:wim:Z:\sources\install.wim:1 /LimitAccess`.

When running `/RestoreHealth` with `/LimitAccess` and no `/Source`, Microsoft says:

> If you do not specify a /Source for the repair files, the default location for Features on Demand is used.

Source: [Repair a Windows Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image?view=windows-10)

**My Question**

Where is the *Features on Demand* location? Should I use it? Does it use the same (or similar) files as the install.wim from the installation media?

My machines are permanently and intentionally disconnected from Windows Update. I have the source install.wim available from the installation media.

Comment: WinSxS *is* the component store location. So running `/RestoreHealth /LimitAccess` without `/Source` would complete instantly because it would be comparing files against itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the
[Features On Demand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities?view=windows-11)
using the command:

```
DISM /online /get-capabilities
```

I chose one installed package : `XPS.Viewer~~1.0.mum`.

Searching for locations where this package exists on the disk, I found
two locations:

- `C:\Windows\servicing\InboxFodMetadataCache\metadata\`
- `C:\Windows\servicing\WUFodMetadataCache\metadata\`

Unfortunately, I can find no further information about these two folders,
but I believe that they are the folders that will be used by DISM.

Comment: Good info, thank you. Now I'm just wondering how the contents of C:\Windows\servicing differs from Z:\sources\install.wim:1. I have a feeling this will remain one of life's great unsolved mysteries.